# Groups permissions for multiple users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, file-permissions, user-groups

I am setting up a web development uBuntu server for multiple users.

The website files are all owned by **root** and in the group **root**.

As I was trying to avoid giving parts of the file structure **777** permissions, I tried solving my problem by using user groups with the following lines of code:

```
user@localhost:~$ sudo groupadd developers
user@localhost:~$ grep 'developers' /etc/group
user@localhost:~$ sudo usermod -a -G developers user
user@localhost:~$ sudo chown -R root:developers test
user@localhost:~$ sudo chmod 664 test
user@localhost:~$ ll

.
.
.
-rw-rw-r--  1 root developers    0 Oct 10 11:33 test
```

- I add my "developers" group
- I confirm my developers group exists
- I add an existing user to the new group
- I change the group of a test file from root to developers
- I give the group read and write permissions on the test file
- I list the contents of the directory to confirm the group and permissions have been correctly altered

With all those steps accomiplished, attempts to save the *test* file are still unsuccessful.

Am I doing something wrong, please?

Comment: What are you using to edit the file? If it's an application that tries to rename the old file to keep a backup before writing a new file that could be a reason (lacking directory permissions).

Comment: I mounted the remote file structure to my local harddrive and I edit them using sublime

Comment: What are permissions of the folder where your file `test` is situated? If it lacks write permissions for the corresponding group you can not write to this file even if it has write prmission.

Comment: The containing folder has 664 permissions

Comment: With such folder permissions you can not operate with the content of this folder as a nonroot user unless you set an execution bit (--x). In your case, if your folder group permission is 6 and you want to alter content of the file inside this folder with the same group (developers), you need odd 1,3,5 or 7 permissions for the folder group. With 1 and 3 you can alter the file content being outside the folder, because you can not enter it without enabled read permission (4). With 5 and 7 you can alter the file content being within this folder.